# Was the function called before from a specific address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, accounts

Consider a function definition as below -

```
function checkForUpvote() external returns(bool){
```

*Here I would first like to check, if the external account invoking this function 
: has **invoked this function before ?**. If yes, exit. Else Continue.*

```
// ......
// ......<function definition follows>
}
```

**Question:** how can I check that checkForUpvote() is invoked only once by one account. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mapping (address => bool) private hasUpvoted;

function checkForUpvote() external returns(bool) {
    require(!hasUpvoted[msg.sender], 'You already upvoted');

    [... do stuff]

    hasUpvoted[msg.sender] = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Markus for a quick response. If I may ask you and the community - is it possible or are there any other functions that solidity provides - which can do the same check ?. By that way, we can achieve the same without having to define an extra mapping variable like hasUpvoted. Is that possible ?.

Comment: @rajatBlock What's your problem with using a mapping? The information if a user already called the function has to be stored somewhere, there is no extra EVM function for that.

Comment: No problem :) . This was more from information perspective, in case there is an option.